# Is there any auto indentation for formatted code

Tags: feature-request, support, code-formatting

Is it possible to add auto indentation for code.

For example:

```
do
{
for(;true;)
{
}

}while(true);
```

The nested scope isn't auto indented. I have to do it manually.
Is it possible to add the feature or it exists already?

Comment: And F5 to compile and run? :)

Comment: @Bejol: That would be too much to ask for :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic code reindent button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/automatic-code-reindent-button)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard enough to find a library that will [tidy up HTML](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), then you need to [prettify JS](http://jsbeautifier.org/) within HTML files, and on top of that CSS.  That's only considering core web development.

Then you have [SQL formatting](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm), C#, VB.net, *nix scripts, [dos batch files](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/batch-mode.el), [Delphi](http://jedicodeformat.sourceforge.net/), Haskell, [Perl](http://www.extremeperl.org/bk/coding-style), Python, Smalltalk, Ruby...

Each with its own language specification. For some languages, the formatting itself defines code blocks (begin-end), so you really don't want to guess on those ones.

Even if you can find a good formatter for EVERY SINGLE LANGUAGE StackOverflow<sup>1</sup> supports (and that means ***all and sundry*** under the sun), can you even get developers to *like* the implicit formatting rules imposed by SE?

<sup>1</sup> *That is without even considering all the other sites on the SE2 sites that share the same engine*

Comment: So, can we hop on this or what?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a customized version of jsbeautifier's userscript, that does your example code from,

[image]

To

[image]

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/99808.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/99808)

- only tested on chrome 11 dev, firefox 3.6
- I have only @included http://*stackoverflow.com
- might have some issues with existing syntax highligher

Comment: I went to the site, but not quite sure how to use it. Is this some kind of plugin?

Comment: @Gunner, yeah, thats browser extensions, use to called greasemonkey or userscript, more info here http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info, but currently, above script has some issues with existing syntax highligher script in stackoverflow, so I am not recommand to install that at the moment.