# [Request] Can you add shortcut key for code formatting?

Tags: feature-request, support, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there any auto indentation for formatted code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84718/is-there-any-auto-indentation-for-formatted-code)
>   [Automatic code reindent button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/automatic-code-reindent-button)

I read a bit of similar posts about indenting code on Stack Overflow, it seems that there's no shortcut key, or icon to format or indent the code.

Could you please add a shortcut key to format or properly indent code blocks?

What i mean is that currently there's only color formatting according to tags.
When you press cntrl+K:

```
class Blah {
Void func() 
{

}

}
```

There's no indentation.

Even in stackoverflow with proper tagging, it won't indent the code.

Comment: This is a request. Not a question. It was changed to a question as a misunderstanding by an editor.

Comment: It's not the same, this is not a question, it's a request...

Comment: Please don' add pseudo [tags] to question titles. We already have real tags.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/automatic-code-reindent-button) is the request. It's already been made. Vote it up if you want to support it.

Answer (score 3):

There's already a shortcut key: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

The icon is the pair of curly braces in the toolbar: `{}`

Where in the world did you get the idea that neither of these existed?

Comment: That does not fix formatting or indentation. it just marks the text.

Comment: @Yochai: It doesn't "fix" the indentation, what would that even mean anyway?  It merely adds (or removes) indentation levels for currently selected code.

Comment: @Yochai it does fix formatting in that it indents blocks of text so that they appear as code, but it doesn't automatically indent the code for you and that's such a stylistic preference that it's unlikely to happen

Comment: I'm talking ab out actual formatting, like you have in IDE (eclipse, VS) or even paste-bin sites

Comment: Just do a test, ask a question, just declare a class, and function, press cntrl+k on it, and post .... there will b e no indentation

Comment: @Yochai: Oh, so you're talking about *automatic* formatting of code? No, that's not been implemented yet, at least to my knowledge. However, if you're using Chrome, you could try the [textarea formatter extension](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-textarea-formatter/). For what it's worth, I'd prefer that the site not try and automatically format my code...

Comment: @Yochai it's indented, but that just causes the Markdown formatting to treat it as code, that 's it

Comment: Right, that's why I initially tagged this is a request. I'll change it to "formatting" instead of indenting so there won't be any more misunderstandings.

Comment: Fair enough, the retag was my mistake. Feel free to roll it back to "feature-request". But keep in mind, that in *many* languages, whitespace is significant. Automatic formatting like you mention would require a pretty robust syntax processor, and would probably cause as many problems as it solved.