# 4 spaces key binding to help manual code formatting

Tags: feature-request

Although the code block does a good job of auto formatting code most of time it does mess up occasionally and when editing often exhibits some strange behavior such as splitting the code block which can result in bad formatting which is not corrected by re-selecting code block.

Is there anyway as a work around you could map a key to produce 4 spaces, It would make life sooo much easier when correcting code layout.

Comment: I think it's because the tab bar is used by the browser to change focus to the next input box.

Comment: yeh I get that, but couldn't Ctrl+space or something similar be mapped to do it

Comment: After you paste the code, just select it all and hit Ctrl-K to indent it all at once.

Comment: really? ...I'm gonna go try that

Comment: Yes, really: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: No no no, that just does the same thing as the code block button - I know about that, which dont get me wrong works great sometimes. But when you start editing it to strip parts out or add comments it often goes wrong - or if you have tab space mixes. It's when you need to correct it it becomes a pain

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts

Comment: @balpha Just took a look at that link, and that is exactly what I want. But it's not what happens when I use SO, cause if I press tab it moves out the question box. What do I do with the download to make it happen?

Comment: Depends on the browser you're using, see http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

Comment: Then vote for [Automatic code reindent button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/automatic-code-reindent-button)?

Comment: @Arjan - I've just done that, What I am asking for is what has been suggested as the answer (not whats asked in the question - I suspected that was asking a lot) - increase/decrease indent buttons with a shortcut key

Comment: @balpha thanks for the link, I will get that set up

Answer (score 1):

What I do is that I write a all of the code I need to the post, or paste all of the code in, then I highlight it and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: I didnt know about the shortcut but I knew about the code block. I'm speaking more about when the auto-formatting doesnt work properly... which seems to happen a lot especially when editing in the question window